# Stemming words in a list (Python NLTK)

Tags: python, list, loops, nltk, stemming

I feel like I'm doing something really stupid here, I am trying to stem words I have in a list but it is not giving me the intended outcome, my code is:

```
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer
snowball = SnowballStemmer(language="english")
my_words = ['works', 'shooting', 'runs']
for w in my_words:
    w=snowball.stem(w)
print(my_words)
```

and the ouput I get is

```
['works', 'shooting', 'runs]
```

as opposed to

```
['work','shoot','run']
```

I feel like I'm doing something very silly with my list but could anyone enlighten me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You do nothing with `w` in your loop

Comment: `w=snowball.stem(w)` would do nothing to `my_words`. Try appending to a output array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list comprehension :

```
[snowball.stem(word) for word in my_words]
```

Answer (score 0):

Silly me,

I just created a new list inside and append to it to give the intended outcome:

```
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer
snowball = SnowballStemmer(language="english")
new_list=[]
my_words = ['works', 'shooting']
for w in my_words:
    w=snowball.stem(w)
    new_list.append(w)
print(new_list)
```